# how to validate if nothing is selected from drop-down using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to validate if nothing is selected from drop-down then i want to show a message to remind users to select something from the drop-down.  I have tried this code but it is not working so not sure what am i doing wrong here.  here is my code:
here is my button in aspx in the gridview:

```
<FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"   OnClientClick="return Validate();"  />
         </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Validate() {
   if (document.getElementById("ddlProject").value == "") {
       alert("Please select value"); // prompt user
       document.getElementById("ddlProject").focus(); //set focus back to control
        return false;
         }
       }

   </script>
```

Comment: The ID  is wrong, ASP.NET assigns a new ID to its elements unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use your drop down lists .net ID in javascript. Use its ClientID:

```
document.getElementById("<%=ddlProject.ClientID%>")
```

When asp.net renders the html equivalent of your controls, it doesn't always keep the id the same.

Comment: i get the message to pop up but i then got this error:Error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: it does not like the line where i set the focus.  that is the issue